# Regex to check even number of preceding characters

Tags: java, regex

I needed to ensure the string doesn't end with `\'` so used negative look behind:

`\\:'(.+)(?<!\\\\)'`

However, it could end with `\\'`. Basically, it could end with `'` or `'` preceded by the even number of backslashes `\`.

It is implemented in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way

`(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*'$`

Explained

```
 (?<! \\ )          # Not an escape behind us, forces only even escapes ahead
 (?: \\ \\ )*       # Any amount of even escapes
 '                  # Quote 
 $                  # EOS
```

Notes - It is a fact that even escapes don't escape anything, so to   enforce that only even escapes can be ahead, a negative look behind `(?<!\\)` is used.

Comment: I would be very grateful if you can share with us your thoughts on how you composed this regex.  I saw some explanations in Andreas's answer, but I am feeling not enough.

Comment: This is basically it. Tuned it to meet my more specific needs but the detection works great.

Comment: @Peipei - added some comments.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as a regex to find what you don't want, then include that regex in a zero-width negative lookahead. Description below uses `xxx` to indicate regex built up to that point.

You want to find `\'` at the end: `\\'$`

You want to include even number of `\` before that. `(?:\\\\)*xxx`

You don't want a `\` before that: `(?<!\\)xxx`

Anything before that is allowed: `.*xxx`

Embed in a negative lookahead then match anything: `^(?!xxx).*$`

Make sure `.` matches line breaks (optional): `(?s)xxx`

All combined: `(?s)^(?!.*(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\'$).*$`

As a Java literal: `"(?s)^(?!.*(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\\\\\)*\\\\'$).*$"`

Demo on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/goNbti/1) shows that lines ending with odd number of `\` before final `'` is not selected, i.e. is invalid.